# ArcGIS API for JavaScript - Adding Point(s)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson, html5, arcgis-api-wpf

I need to add a single point, I am new to JS and ArcGIS API. I was looking for some code examples on how to create a point and/or a few other points (as needed) I can't use any additional pages/external sources, as in the code needs to be in my single page. I found examples like the button add a point, but I don't need a button I just need to place a point or points with their respective coordinates. Then style as necc. Can someone provide either code or a link so I can do this simple task? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first stop to all things help related is ArcGIS.com.
But also the [developer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) site is where you will find what you need.
You will have to create a template for your feature layer and handle the security but otherwise this sample should be what you want.
[Edit without widget](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/ed_feature_creation/)

and here is the [code page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_feature_creation.html)